# Use of square brackets in probability notation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

So, (from what I know) square brackets and parenthesis normally refer to a structures like this:

$[1,5] = 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5$

$[1,5) = 1, 2 , 3, 4$

etc.

However, I once saw the concept of discrete probability distributions written in the manner below. A discrete probability distribution $D$ over the set $[D]$ is specified:

$Prob_{\,D}[u] \in [0,1] \;$ for all $ \; u \in [D]$

So in this case, does $[0,1]$ refer to the continuous range of real numbers from $0 \rightarrow 1 \;$?

Or does it refer to just the discrete range? I don't think it can be the latter as it is later stated that:

$\sum_{u \, \in \, D} Prob_{\,D}[u] = 1 $

Which isn't possible if

$Prob_{\,D}[u]=1$

for more than one $u$. How should I interpret this?

Comment: From what I understand (I may be wrong) this is just saying that the probability of the event $u$ is a number in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of notations, according to [ISO 31-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11).

$$[a,b]= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x \leq b \}$$

$$[a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x < b \}$$

An author need not follow the convention and you might like to check if it is defined in your book.

Comment: Okay, I think they combine the definition in your answer with the discrete version i.e. I think e.g. $[1,5] = 1,2,3,4,5$ whilst $[0,1] = \{x \in R : 0 \leq x \leq b\}$ depending on the context.

Comment: I see. For discrete points, sometimes I write
 $$\{1, \ldots, 5 \}=[1,5] \cap \mathbb{Z}.$$ Out of curiousity,  may I know which book use the same notation for both discrete and continuous?

Comment: Actually, ignore my prior comment. I think they *only* use your definition. There is no instance of the paper where square brackets must denote a discrete set. My confusion came purely from this stackexchange question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last and they explicitly state they're *assuming integers*. So I think that's case closed.

Comment: And yes, to add a final point, the author of the book I'm reading specifically writes $ \{0,1\}$ when referring to the set formed of only $0$ and $1$ (which matches your comment)!